# Xcode Server is unavailable

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots

I am trying to setup CI on an Xcode Server. I have a Mac running OSX Server with Xcode Services up and running (seems to be working). The Mac is hosted in the cloud.

When I try to add the server to Xcode on my local Mac dev machine, it says "Xcode Server is unavailable". What "server address" do I use. I tried the IP address as well as the machinename.companyname.com address.

Note I have enabled the "file sharing" service and this works fine using machinename.companyname.com.

Comment: Which Xcode & Mac OS version ?

Comment: Xcode Server: Mac OS = 10.9.4, Xcode = 5.1.1.  On my "Local Mac", Mac OS = 10.9.5, Xcode = 6.0.

Comment: Same problem here after update to XCode6

Comment: @Reinhard Did you upgrade to Yosemite?

Comment: @Nick: Unfortunately Yosemite is not yet available in Germany. I hope it will solve my problems. I asked an apparently related question on SO <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995339/cannot-access-repositories-on-os-x-server-3-2-1-with-xcode-6-0-1> but did not yet have success in accessing my repositories again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem.  After upgrading to Xcode6, need to upgrade to Yosemite too.  Don't know why but this seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I configured my router to forward the relevant traffic to the server. This process is called port forwarding.

Opening these ports worked for me

```
Protocol    Port Range  ----    Comment
TCP         22          ----    ssh 
TCP         80          ----    http    
TCP         443         ----    https   
TCP+UDP     3690        ----    svn 
TCP+UDP     9418        ----    git 
TCP+UDP     20300       ----    xcode1  
TCP+UDP     20343-20345 ----    xcode2
```

reference: https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT202944

Comment: It's interesting to note the 20300, 20343-20345 ports are not listed on the linked support document, but are required (in my testing) for Xcode to communicate with the Xcode server (as of this writing).

Comment: Interesting, I see they updated the document from April 21, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem you are. My server is not in the cloud, but it is setup to be accessible outside of my network. I am able to add my server because it is seen by Bonjour. Everything works fine that way. However, I can't add the server by using the IP or the www address.

I've verified that TCP ports 22, 80, and 443 are forwarding correctly. I also have TCP/UDP 3690 and 9418 forwarded correctly.

One thing I wanted to add is that I can add repositories that exist on the server without issue. It is just adding the server that is causing a problem.

I have filed a bug report with Apple and will comment back here as soon as I get a response.

Comment: Thanks Brian, let us know what they say

Comment: I still haven't received any action on my bug report, but I noticed that it didn't have a rank. I adjusted the rank to high so hopefully it will get picked up. I will try upgrading to Yosemite tomorrow and see if it resolves the issue. Hopefully I have the same luck that Nick had.